# Post a link to a Facebook Application page with an application access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to get my Django application to post all new news stories to the application's facebook page. It works posting to /feed, but if I try to post to /links with the access token given like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-as-an-application), I get the following error:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#282) Requires extended permission: share_item
```

Surely I should be able to post to the application page of my application using this access token? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the code in the Python-SDK for Facebook, I worked this out: you have to use the put_wall_post function with the link supplied in a dictionary as shown [in the source](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.py).

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Hi Ben i got the same error , but i didnt understand what is wrong, i use php curl to post data to my facebook page, i have token and it says i have permisson to share item but i cant.
what should i do ?

that was my question and finaly i solved it.

Even if you have the permissons you have to have an extended permisson like "manage_page" so to get this, you should enter this url :

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token

and than no errors ;)